# Concatenating a C# List of byte[]

Tags: c#, list, arrays, concatenation

I am creating several byte arrays that need to be joined together to create one large byte array - i'd prefer not to use byte[]'s at all but have no choice here...

I am adding each one to a List as I create them, so I only have to do the concatenation once I have all the byte[]'s, but my question is, what is the best way of actually doing this?

When I have a list with an unknown number of byte[]'s and I want to concat them all together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
listOfByteArrs.SelectMany(byteArr=>byteArr).ToArray()
```

The above code will concatenate a sequence of sequences of bytes into one sequence - and store the result in an array.

Though readable, this is not maximally efficient - it's not making use of the fact that you *already know* the length of the resultant byte array and thus can avoid the dynamically extended `.ToArray()` implementation that necessarily involves multiple allocations and array-copies.  Furthermore, `SelectMany` is implemented in terms of iterators; this means lots+lots of interface calls which is quite slow.  However, for small-ish data-set sizes this is unlikely to matter.

*If* you need a faster implementation you can do the following:

```
var output = new byte[listOfByteArrs.Sum(arr=>arr.Length)];
int writeIdx=0;
foreach(var byteArr in listOfByteArrs) {
    byteArr.CopyTo(output, writeIdx);
    writeIdx += byteArr.Length;
}
```

or as Martinho suggests:

```
var output = new byte[listOfByteArrs.Sum(arr => arr.Length)];
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(output))
    foreach (var bytes in listOfByteArrs)
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Some timings:

```
var listOfByteArrs = Enumerable.Range(1,1000)
    .Select(i=>Enumerable.Range(0,i).Select(x=>(byte)x).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Using the short method to concatenate these 500500 bytes takes 15ms, using the fast method takes 0.5ms on my machine - YMMV, and note that for many applications both are more than fast enough ;-).

Finally, you could replace `Array.CopyTo` with the `static` `Array.Copy`, the low-level `Buffer.BlockCopy`, or a `MemoryStream` with a preallocated back buffer - these all perform pretty much identically on my tests (x64 .NET 4.0).

Comment: Though short and clear, note that this code is very slow compared to the traditional solution. If it's fast enough, great, but it might not be fast enough.

Comment: Which is the "traditional solution"?

Comment: The "traditional" solution would probably be manual, nested for loops.  That's about three times slower than the block-copy based solutions, but still 10 times faster than `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution based on [Andrew Bezzub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875968/concatenating-a-c-list-of-byte/4876042#4876042)'s and [fejesjoco's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875968/concatenating-a-c-list-of-byte/4876023#4876023), pre-allocating all the memory needed up front. This yields Θ(N) memory usage and Θ(N) time (N being the total number of bytes).

```
byte[] result = new byte[list.Sum(a => a.Length)];
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(result))
{
    foreach (byte[] bytes in list)
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

write them all to a MemoryStream instead of a list. then call MemoryStream.ToArray(). Or when you have the list, first summarize all the byte array lengths, create a new byte array with the total length, and copy each array after the last in the big array.

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq:

```
    List<byte[]> list = new List<byte[]>();
    list.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    list.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    list.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

    IEnumerable<byte> result = Enumerable.Empty<byte>();

    foreach (byte[] bytes in list)
    {
        result = result.Concat(bytes);
    }

    byte[] newArray = result.ToArray();
```

Maybe faster solution would be (not declaring array upfront):

```
IEnumerable<byte> bytesEnumerable = GetBytesFromList(list);

byte[] newArray = bytesEnumerable.ToArray();

private static IEnumerable<T> GetBytesFromList<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> list)
{
    foreach (IEnumerable<T> elements in list)
    {
        foreach (T element in elements)
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like above would iterate each array only once.

Comment: Note that this solution is O(n^2) in the number of byte arrays. (Do you see why? Hint: sequence operators are *lazy*.) You can do better than that. Can you find a solution that is linear in the number of byte arrays?

Comment: @Eric: thanks! It was not obvious for me that the solution is O(n^2). What if I use separate method to form enumerable of bytes? I updated the answer.

Comment: What's laziness got to do with it?  A non-lazy implementation would be O(N^2) too.  Conversely, you could have a lazy sequence and O(N) performance.  The problem is the required interface wrapping - you need to successively wrap enumerators - you can't declare a continuation.  It's not an entirely fair comparison but in, say, Haskell conceptually similar code would for instance be lazy *and* O(N).

Comment: Indeed. **Now generalize it.** That doesn't have to be List<byte[]>; it could be IEnumerable<byte[]> since you do not use any property of List other than it being enumerable.  And similarly, it doesn't have to be byte[]; you use no property of byte, or of arrays. It's all sequences! In C# 4 you could say IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> items) { foreach(var sequence in items) foreach(T t in sequence) yield return t; } and be done with it. (This depends on covariance of IEnumerable<T>, so it only works in C# 4; there are ways to make it work in C# 3 with more type params.)

Comment: Of course you could generalize that even further to IEnumerable<R> Flatten<T, R>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, IEnumerable<R>> selector) { foreach(T item in items) foreach(R result in selector(item)) yield return result; } and hey, you just invented SelectMany; this method is already in the sequence operator library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing each byte array into a `List<byte[]>`, you could instead add them directly to a `List<byte>`, using the [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method for each one.

Answer (score -1):

hmm how about [list.addrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)?

Comment: Does AddRange convert a List into a byte[]? No.