# List of byte[] to one big byte[]

Tags: c#, list, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenating a C# List of byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875968/concatenating-a-c-sharp-list-of-byte)

I have a list of `byte[]` and I would like to combine this list to one big `byte[]`. I have tried several ways but I seem to lost some of the data when I try to combine the bytes.

Here is one of the ways I have tried:

```
byte[] comebined = listOfBytes.Cast<byte[]>()
                   .Select(x => x)
                   .SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

My question here is how can I combine a list of `byte[]` into one big `byte[]` and making sure that none of data is lost. Efficency is not an issue in this matter, as long as it works.

All the help is very appreciated.

Comment: You have tried something but "it didn't work". You "seem to have lost data". Describe this in much more detail.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that would lose any data. Where does the data come from? Is it possible that the data is lost already at an earlier stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listOfBytes.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: While that should work, it's the same thing as what's in the question: both the `Cast<byte[]>()` and `Select(x => x)` effectively do nothing. If the snippet in the question *doesn't* work, neither will your answer.

Comment: @hvd I tested it before posting :) I don't know what the OP does wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SelectMany()`

```
listOfBytes.SelectMany(n => n);
```

will give you an `IEnumerable<byte>` object if you want to convert it to byte[], you can do so by

```
listOfBytes.SelectMany(n => n).ToArray()
```